# Що таке "парло" і чи є якийсь сучасний відповідник?

Tags: значення-слів, синоніми

В творі "Конотопська відьма" знайшов такі рядки:

> Ще чи буде після такого **парла** дощ, чи ні, хто його зна, а що ми
>   голодуємо, так се певно.

От цікавить слово "парло", бо його нема в СУМі. Однак, з контексту можна зрозуміти, що це, напевно, жарка і волога погода (можливо походить від слова "[парити](http://sum.in.ua/s/paryty)"). Більше цікавить чи є якесь слово в українській мові, яке б мало таке ж значення (якщо я його вірно визначив), але його можна було б знайти в словниках?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/934832.html)

> парло
> -а, с. , рідко.Пара в лазні.
> *Парла завдати — відшмагати.*

Гадаю відповідником може бути слово "паркий".

> [Паркий](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/934808.html) - а, - е
> 1》 Дуже насичений теплою парою, вологою.
> 2》 Жаркий, душний внаслідок надмірних випарів.
> 3》 Від якого йде пара; який випускає теплі випари.

Таке ж значення слова "паркий" подає [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/Parkyj)
Отже, може бути  словосполучення "парка погода"